# Check for odd or even in array in liquid

Tags: jekyll, shopify, liquid

If there is any way to check for odd or even in array.size, for example?

```
{% if.collections.size == EVEN %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: doesn't that programming language have **module**? try `if.collections.size %2 == 0`

Comment: no, there is no way to check like that

Comment: as was shown below, I was wrong, there is a way to use module/modulo

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Refer to the Maths Modulo filter:
http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/output#modulo

```
{% assign value = collections.size | modulo:2 %}
{% if value == 0 %}
  even
{% else %}
  odd
{% endif %}
```

Or if you'd prefer a one liner:

```
{{ collections.size | modulo:2 | plus:1 | pluralize:'even','odd' }}
```

Comment: This one liner is great, thanks! However, I see you can only use 'pluralize' on Shopify, not in standalone Liquid or Jekyll Liquid. So here is an equivalent one-liner for those: `{{ collections.size | modulo: 2 | replace: '0', 'even' | replace: '1', 'odd' }}`.

Answer (score 0):

after some experiments, I found the solution, maybe for anyone will be helpfull

```
   {% assign even = false %}
  {% for collection in collections %}
   {% capture u %}{% cycle 'odd', 'even' %}{% endcapture %}
  {% if u == 'even' %}
  {% assign even = true %}
  {{u}}
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% if even == true %}
  collection-even
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int arr[20] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
cout << "The Even no are : \n";
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) // for start for only i....(even nos)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << i;
        cout << " ";
    }
}
cout << "\nThe Odd no are : \n";
for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) // for start for only j....(odd nos)
{
    if (j % 2 != 0)
    {
        cout << j;
        cout << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this relevant? the question is for Liquid, not C++